# Should I worry about CFLs (Compact Fluorescent Lamps) skunking my beer?

Tags: flavor, spoilage, skunk, techniques

Particularly when racking from primary to secondary and then again into the keg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments in Jack Smiths post, however, I'll offer this answer to the Original Posters question.

If you have the "racking from" and the "racking to" vessels protected from light during the racking process, the short time the beer spends flowing through the tubing should produce a miniscule amount of skunk and be undetectable.
The amount of UV from CFLs is fairly mild and shouldn't harm the beer during the "quick" passage vessel to vessel.
So no you should not worry about your CFLs while racking...I don't.

While the other post referenced in JackSmiths answer links to a great info about the speed of skunking; and scientific data regarding the speed at which CFLs can cause skunking has yet to bubble to the surface of the homebrewing community/knowledge base.

Comment: I'll add that I have a CFL over my kitchen sink and it's always on when I rack there, from a clear carboy to a clear carboy.  I've never noticed any skunking.  I mostly brew dark beers, but last summer I made a belgian wit and it came out great.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer to [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/skunking-beer-process).

Comment: Not exactly sure why this was voted down. Aside from not addressing the question of racking, it is an acceptable answer.

Comment: I'm at a loss, too.  The answer I linked to goes into detail about what causes skunking, and describes that the offending wavelength comes from the sun as well as from fluorescent lamps.

Comment: BrewAdvisors: when you vote an answer down, please add some constructive criticism.

Comment: Wasn't me! But yes, when voting down, please leave a note as to why so that user can fix the issue.

Comment: This link is broken. Can you fix it or delete the answer?

Comment: Done.  Apparently it wasn't updated when brewadvice was merged into homebrew.stackexchange however long ago.

Comment: I suspect the reason it was voted down is because "Look at this question" answers belong in the comments.